# Xamarin Forms inner navigation with bottom menu

Tags: xamarin.forms

Here is a representation of what I want to accomplish in Xamarin Forms (Android & iOS):

[image]

The bottom area is not a tab control because we can navigate to another page OR open a drop down menu at the page top level.

I was wondering if it was possible to have UI (like this menu at the bottom of the page) with an area where it is possible to navigate in Xamarin Forms. For example in UWP we can accomplish that by having a [Frame control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame) inside the page.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout With absolutelayout you can overlap objects.

Comment: But we can't overlay a navigation view.

Comment: You can use Custom Renderer and implement it in specific platforms ,check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/169544/disable-clipping-of-tabbedpage